What kind of bearing do I need?
I want to create a hammer saw weapon for a battle bot like Sawblaze and, lacking the design of saw blaze, I'm wondering what kind of bearing I need for various parts of the hammer saw weapon.
I have three axles. One axle is for turning the saw blade and there is a second to move the "arm" up and down. The "arm" being the hammer part of the hammer saw. Suppose there was a gear with a bearing in it placed on the first axle.
The problem is that the bearing has to handle axle 1 spinning in one direction to move the arm as well as motor B spinning the gear itself to spin the saw on the second axle. I need to have the flexibility to move the arm and spin the saw at the same time, my concern is that I would damage the bearing fairly quickly.
Sawblaze, in a YouTube video, says they used something called an intermediate sheave to solve the problem but I haven't been able to find something that looks like what they have. My guess is that I would need a bearing within a bearing to handle the task.


I might be showing my ignorance, but what is "Sawblaze". Also, link to YT video? Please [edit] and update your question.
